# How to rewrite this SQL statement to LINQ 2 SQL?

Tags: sql, linq-to-sql

How can i convert this SQL query to its equivalent LINQ 2 SQL statement for VB.NET?

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'Qty', 
 IV200.itemnmbr,
 IV200.locncode,
 IV200.bin,
 CAST(IV112.Quantity as int) as 'Qty2' ,
 'parentBIN' = isnull(MDS.parentBIN,iv112.bin) 
   From IV00200 IV200 (nolock)
     inner join  IV00112 IV112 (nolock)
                      on  iv200.itemnmbr = iv112.itemnmbr 
                      and IV200.bin = IV112.bin
                      and iv200.locncode = iv112.locncode 
     left outer join  mds_container mds (nolock) 
                      on isnull(mds.locncode,'nul') = isnull(iv112.locncode,'nul') 
                      and isnull(mds.containerbin,'nul') = isnull(iv112.bin,'nul') 
                      where IV200.bin = 'MU7I336A80'
    group by IV200.itemnmbr, 
             IV200.locncode, 
             IV200.bin,
             IV112.Quantity,
             isnull(MDS.parentBIN,iv112.bin) 
    order by IV200.itemnmbr
```

Comment: My eyes! That needs serious formatting

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at a product named `Linqer (www.sqltolinq.com)`. We use this in house to convert more complex SQL queries to Linq. It's not free, but it's not expensive either, and comes with a 30 day trial.